# How to parse OpenAM XACML using JVM?

Tags: java, openam, xacml, opensso, forgerock

We are using OpenAM as STS and its Policy Decision for ACL. I need the list of all url/methods for some task and I can retrieve XACML using OpenAM RESTful services. there are tons of XACMl libraries in JAVA ecosystem. Some of them are obsolete and others are new. I am trying t use At&T XACML library but it has not a rich documentation. How can I parse OpenAM output and get list of uri/mthod?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply generate Java objects via JAXB. This would let you read / write XACML 3.0 artifacts (policies and requests / responses).